# Deck transformation orbit space is a covering space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let p : E → B be a covering map.

Assume that B is locally path connected and that H is a subgroup of Aut(p).

> Show that p induces a covering map E/H → B, where E/H denotes the quotient of E by
> the equivalence relation x ∼ hx, for all h∈H

The induced map I think is [x] → p(x) which I checked is well-defined. Why is it a covering map? Previously I have seen that the H action is properly discontinuous.

Comment: Why did you check if $H$ acts properly discontinuously?